# How can I share a particular account using manual sharing?

Tags: sharing

I want to share a particular account to different users in organization.I try to use the sharing button  on the account record and when I try to add that users,it shows me the message that selected sharing settings is already included in your organization.Please increase account access to be greater than your organization default?

Currently I am the admin.Do I need to increase the access by going to profile for each users or by default are all users able to see the account record which I created

kINDLY HELP!!

Comment: Whats the OWD for those Users for Account object?If they already have access to same then you will get that error .You can only share to users who don't have access to those Accounts currently .

Comment: If I go under profile for a particular users and under Standard Object Permissions,the profile has been given as basic access and not the data administration,how do I see the owd settings for that user?

Comment: Ok Mohith,if I go under security settings and under sharing settings I see that OWD for Account is Public Read/Write ?Does it mean it is already shared right?

Comment: Exactly !!! Public read/write means its shared and accessible .

Comment: See the Trailhead link .Go through them for better understanding of data security in salesforce

Answer (score 2):

Whats the OWD for those Users for Account object?

> If they already have access to same then you will get that error .You can only share to users who don't have access to those Accounts currently

I would recommend you to go through security Trailhead

https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/data_security